# Shisha Asar Ushlosh Meyot - mi yodeya?

Tags: number, mi-yodeya-series

### Who knows three hundred sixteen?

### ?שישה עשר ושלוש מאות - מי יודע

In the spirit of the song ["Echad - mi yodeya"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Echad_Mi_Yodea), please post interesting and significant Jewish facts about the number 316.

And ... there is *that* lazy gematria available here, but let's not go there.

Check out [mi-yodeya-series](/questions/tagged/mi-yodeya-series) for the previous three hundred fifteen entries in this ongoing series.

Please include sources for your information wherever possible, as with all other answers on this site.

Comment: Is that a pun on אותו?

Comment: @DoubleAA, that's one of two intended puns.

Comment: ahh HaIsh == 316

Comment: 316 is an anagram for 613 the number of mitzvos :)

Comment: @DoubleAA, I hadn't thought of "ha-ish." There are two simple gematriot alluded to.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Three hundred sixteen were the recorded disagreements between [Beit Hillel and Beit Shammai](http://www.jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/3190-bet-hillel-and-bet-shammai).

-- [*Jewish Encyclopedia*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jewish_Encyclopedia)

Answer (score 3):

[The Aruch used the Peirish of Rabbenu Chananel 316 times for Mesechtas Shabbos](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=48236&st=&pgnum=512&hilite=)

Comment: Why is this significant?

Comment: @DoubleAA, the community has IME traditionally allowed less obviously significant answers in the [tag:mi-yodeya-series] than for other questions.

Comment: @msh210, Allowed, yes. However, This question explicitly asks for "interesting and significant," so it makes sense to challenge answerers to explain how their answers fulfill that standard. There may be a significance here that is not currently clear in the answer.

Comment: @Issac Moses: Unfortunately it is very difficult or quiet impossible to have interesting and significant Jewish facts about each number. Sometimes you got to do with whatever there is.

Comment: @GershonGold yaga'ti umatzati ;^P